# I am trying to implement a double-jump into my SFML Platformer but it does not work in the way intended

Tags: c++, sfml

I am trying to make a platformer in SFML for C++ but I can't get button presses to work properly. Trying to double jump does not work and holding down the jump button makes my character continuously jump. Help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "Platformer");
float positionX = 100.0;
float positionY = 175.0;
float velocityX = 0.0;
float velocityY = 0.0;
float gravity = 1.3;
bool onGround = false;
sf::RectangleShape player(sf::Vector2f(5, 5));
sf::RectangleShape block(sf::Vector2f(5, 20));
int jumpCounter = 0;


void MoveLeft()
{
    velocityX = -12;
}

void MoveRight()
{
    velocityX = 12;
}

void StartJump()
{
    if (!onGround && jumpCounter == 0)
    {
        velocityY = -12;
        jumpCounter = 1;
    }
    if(onGround)
    {
        velocityY = -12;
        onGround = false;
        jumpCounter = 1;
    }
}

void EndJump()
{
    if(velocityY > -6)
        velocityY = -6;
}

void Update()
{
    velocityY += gravity/400;
    positionY += velocityY/400;
    positionX += velocityX/400;

    if(positionY > 195.0)
    {
        positionY = 195.0;
        velocityY = 0.0;
        onGround = true;
    }

    if(positionX > 195)
    {
        positionX = 195.0;
    }
    if(positionX < 0)
    {
        positionX = 0;
    }
    player.setPosition(positionX, positionY);
    velocityX = 0.0;
    if (onGround)
        jumpCounter = 0;
}

void Render()
{
    window.clear();
    window.draw(player);
    window.display();
}

int main()
{
    window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event));
        Update();
        Render();
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
            StartJump();
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
            MoveLeft();
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
            MoveRight();

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Care to explain what "double jump" is supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

`sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed()` returns the current state of the provided key. This is `true` if the key is currently depressed, and `false` if it is not.

When the user hits the UP key, it will typically remain depressed for a number of frames. On each of these frames, you test if up is pressed, and `StartJump()` is called. Thus, pressing UP once calls `StartJump()` multiple times. This immediately exhausts both jumps, so you can't actually do the second jump.

You might have more luck listening for the `sf::Event` corresponding to the UP key being pressed. There will only be one such event for each complete keypress.